# Preg_match expression to find code in string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Example strings:

```
$string = "Buyer must enter coupon code 10OFF100 in shopping cart.";
$string = "Get $20 Off Auto Parts Order Over $150. Use Coupon code: GAPCJ20";
```

I need to extract the codes (`10FF100` and `GAPCJ20`).

I was trying to create a `preg_match` to find "coupon code" and "coupon code:" and extract the phrase or word immediately after.  Not having much luck myself or finding the reg expression.

Can some post the proper code please.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this php code:

```
$arr = array("Buyer must enter coupon code 10OFF100 in shopping cart.", "Get $20 Off Auto Parts Order Over $150. Use Coupon code: GAPCJ20");
foreach ($arr as $s) {
   preg_match('~coupon code\W+(\w+)~i', $s, $m);
   var_dump($m[1]);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
string(8) "10OFF100"
string(7) "GAPCJ20"
```

Comment: Why not just `\w` instead of `[^\W]`?

Answer (score 0):

This will match optional `:` with a "code" which is expected to consist of alpha and numeric.

```
/coupon code:? ([a-z0-9]+)/i
```

---

### Will this do?

Short answer: **no**.

So how to make it more efficient? Well the best thing to do would be to **match a regex against a dictionary of lines** that has many examples and formats you want to support. Then keep refining your regex until you get one that is 98% reliable. I say 98% because your probably come to the realization that it will never be perfect as there are so many:

- Possible miss-spellings
- Coupon codes using different characters sets
- Variation of sentences and ordering of words i.e.

  - `Free Coupon: Enter this code 8HFnF5`
  - `Code for coupon (7859NhF)`
  - `Coupons galore! Just put 646GH4 in your basket`
  - `Cupon code is 797gGh`
  - `Your code for free goodies is 4543G5`
  - `Add token "5479_G5t" to your basket for free CD!`
  - ... all of these will fail with the above regex

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:
`/coupon code[:]? ([\w]*)/i`

Answer (score 0):

My try:

```
<?php
if (preg_match('/coupon code:?\s+(.+)(\s+|$)/', $str, $matches)) {
  list(, $code) = $matches;
  echo $code;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For your first variant use

```
Buyer must enter coupon code ([^ ]*) in shopping cart.
```

For the second use

```
Get $20 Off Auto Parts Order Over $150. Use Coupon code: (.*)
```

Comment: I think these are too specific.

Comment: Then define which are the static parts of your strings. Maybe something like:

Answer (score 0):

I do below.

```
preg_match('/[Cc]oupon code:?(\w+)/',$string,$match);
```